# What happens to links, fields and long term ownership if a portal is moved?

Tags: ingress

It's possible to submit a location correction of a portal through the scanner. Unfortunately that is being abused by players of the opposing faction [every once in a while to move home portals](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111134828550212201344/posts/MEtH4AWm6jP) away.

What happens to the state of a portal if it is moved? Will links and fields disappear? Will the resonators disappear and it will spawn grey?

Might it even get a new id (which would be visible in the [intel map](http://www.ingress.com/intel) if you look at links and the source code) and thus count as a new unique visit?

Maybe someone has witnessed this already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a portal is moved, it is lost and recreated as new.

All previous links, fields, and mods are lost.

Comment: So it would also count as a new unique visit?

Comment: @simbabque that I'm unsure about, but could be easily tested?

Comment: Not that easily. You need a moved portal that you know.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to a portal holding an important link at that time (move was genuine, portal was not at its right place).
Links (and so fields) are destroyed, that's quite normal as otherwise portal move could cause crossing links. 
Portal owner, resonators are still there. Mods also (I'm quite sure I would remember if mods had been destroyed)

If you move a wrongly placed duplicate portal at the location of the right one, it can also be destroyed, and pictures added to right portal.